# What is androidx.browser and how to resolve this error Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED?

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, gradle, npm

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
43 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 41 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (33) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-31).
> Dependency: androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0-alpha01.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\akshay.patel.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\41677513f37fd3ff659f9e9ccebf1218\browser-1.5.0-alpha01\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8088

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (33) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-31).
> Dependency: androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0-alpha01.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\akshay.patel.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\41677513f37fd3ff659f9e9ccebf1218\browser-1.5.0-alpha01\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s

```
at makeError (D:\User\mobile\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at D:\User\mobile\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (D:\\mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (D:\User\mobile\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! xyz@0.0.1 dev-local: `npx react-native run-android --port=8088`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the xyz@0.0.1 dev-local script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\akshay.patel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-11-03T08_05_27_690Z-debug.log

**Yes I tried updating my build.gradle by**

```
android {
    compileSdk = "33"

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdk = "33"
    }
}
```

but I still get the same error
please help **Thanks in advance**

Comment: I am getting the exactly same issue for running an existing react native app.

Comment: @PankajPramanik I got the solution it is in the answer section try this I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the root cause of the above problem that **androidx.browser** so I have resolved this by adding the below code snippet in **android/app/build.gradle** file

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0' }
    }
```